# Start and kill background process within one Makefile recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Within one `make` recipe, I am trying to:

1. Run a server process in the background
2. Run a command that uses the server, in the foreground
3. Kill the background server process after foreground task completes

The below is where I am at (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/30171236), but it doesn't quite work because `SERVER_PID` is currently empty (possibly related to this empty PID: [Getting last process' PID in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5768034)).

```
run-server: ## Run the server in the foreground.
    run server

run-kill-server:    ## Run the server while using it.
    @$(MAKE) run-server&
    export SERVER_PID=$! && cmd-that-uses-server && kill $(SERVER_PID)
```

[Makefile run processes in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668311/makefile-run-processes-in-background) is also related, except I believe it "leaks" the background processes, the recipes there don't try to `kill` spawned background processes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Within one make recipe, I am trying to:
>
> 1. Run a server process in the background
> 2. Run a command that uses the server, in the foreground
> 3. Kill the background server process after foreground task completes

But you're *not* doing all that in one recipe.  You're using two.

Bringing it all into one recipe would be a step in the right direction, though It will not in itself provide a complete solution.

> `SERVER_PID` is currently empty

Yes, because your recipe is setting *shell* variable `SERVER_PID`, but trying to reference a *`make`* variable of that name.  And also trying to reference a `make` variable named `!`, where you appear to want the shell variable of that name.  You need to escape your `$` by doubling it when you want to pass it through to the shell.

Additionally, each logical line of your recipe runs in a separate shell.  In the one where you define and later user `SERVER_PID`, no background process is ever run.

You probably want something more like this:

```
run-job:
        run server & export SERVER_PID=$$!; cmd-that-uses-server; kill $${SERVER_PID}
```

Comment: `$${SHELL_ENV_VAR}` is something new to me, thank you!!

Comment: Please read https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html from the manual.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is bash, it keeps a handle to all background processes.

```
./run-server & command-that-uses-server; kill \%1
```

N.B. only one line of text and thus one subshell
N.B. in Makefiles % needs escaping, hence the %1